# Read a registry value from both HKLM and HKLM64 in the code section of InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am having a scenior moment - sorry! :(

Take this code:

```pascal
{ How to Backup }
dwBackupAtShutdownHow := 0;
RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM64,
          'Software\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\Options',
          'BackupAtShutdownMode', dwBackupAtShutdownHow);
if (dwBackupAtShutdownHow = 1) then
begin
  radBackupModeManual.Checked := True;
end
else begin
  radBackupModeAuto.Checked := True;
end;
```

I need to change it so that it will check both `HKLM64` and `HKLM` for the existence of the key. Is this correct:

```pascal
{ How to Backup }
dwBackupAtShutdownHow := 0;
if (IsWin64 and RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM64,
          'Software\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\Options',
          'BackupAtShutdownMode', dwBackupAtShutdownHow))
else
   RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM,
          'Software\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\Options',
          'BackupAtShutdownMode', dwBackupAtShutdownHow);
if (dwBackupAtShutdownHow = 1) then
begin
  radBackupModeManual.Checked := True;
end
else begin
  radBackupModeAuto.Checked := True;
end;
```

Is that the right way to do this?

Comment: It might be correct. And it may not. It depends on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I just want to cover all bases. The installer creates the two entries in both nodes HKLM and HKLM64 (if is win 64). Then `InitializeWizard` reads these settings as they were the last default. So if it is win 64 windows it is safe to read the HKLM64 otherwise the HKLM. I don't want to use the `GetPreviousData` etc because my app will read the HKLM key to get the installed default.

Comment: If you know that the value in HKLM64 exists on all 64-bit systems, than your code is ok.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up with, for example:

```
  if (IsWin64) then
  begin
    RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM64,
            'Software\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\Options',
            'BackupAtShutdownWhat', dwBackupAtShutdownWhat)
  end else   RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM,
            'Software\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\Options',
            'BackupAtShutdownWhat', dwBackupAtShutdownWhat);
```